# how to take Automatic screenshots in ubuntu 12.04 every 2 minutes

Tags: screenshot, automatic, snapshot

I am Ubuntu 12.04 user and I want my machine take automatic screenshots of my work every 2 minutes. So which Software you prefer.
Please suggest me.

Comment: I hope you are not violating anyone's privacy.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this Stack Overflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072424/linux-take-automatic-screenshots-at-random-times

Comment: Ubuntu forums also provides these responses : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1350333

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer ImageMagick.

Note: check applicable privacy laws, as the screenshots may contain confidential data.

Now, on how to do this:

You need to have the ImageMagick package:

```
# apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then, make a Bash script to take the screenshot, save it somewhere (I'm using an example filename of `/path/to/your/script.sh`) and make it executable (`chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# change this for a different date format - see: man date
export DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'`
# display to take the screenshot of
export DISPLAY=:0
# filename to screenshot
export SCREENSHOT_FILENAME="/tmp/screenshot-$DATE.png"
/usr/bin/import -window root "$SCREENSHOT_FILENAME"
```

Last, set up a cron script to do this for you (`crontab -e`, add this line to the end):

```
*/2 *   * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

This will, every two minutes, try to take screenshots of display 0 (which is the default one; if you have a multiseat setup, you may need to find out which window you need), and save them as timestamped PNGs to /tmp (this is an example location which is likely to exist; you may want to use a different directory).

Caveats: there is no checking of free space, so the script may fill up all the space in target location. The script assumes the user is logged in at display :0 (if another user is logged in, user is logged in at different display, or there is no X session, the script will fail).